Is this heat damage to spotted dead-nettle?
I have this planted in a fully sunny spot that only receives water from rain and it's done great. This new bed was doing amazing until the heat and sun picked up. I suspect that it's not the heat and sun alone, but rather the reflection of sunlight from the white siding. Can anyone confirm my suspicions? This area gets morning and early afternoon sun but then becomes shaded in late afternoon. The healthy patch is shaded earlier each day.




Lamium maculatum, or spotted dead nettle, prefers full or part shade conditions and reasonably moist soil - if you have planted in full sun, it won't do so well because the soil probably dries out too much. Further info https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/9812/lamium-maculatum/details
